# How do I mock Read-Host in a Pester test?

Tags: powershell, pester

If i have this function:

```
Function Test-Foo {

    $filePath = Read-Host "Tell me a file path"
}
```

How do i mock the Read-Host to return what i want? e.g. I want to do something like this (which doesn't work):

```
Describe "Test-Foo" {
  Context "When something" {
        Mock Read-Host {return "c:\example"}

        $result = Test-Foo

        It "Returns correct result" {
            $result | Should Be "c:\example"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is correct:

you should change you're code to

```
Import-Module -Name "c:\LocationOfModules\Pester"

Function Test-Foo {
    $filePath = Read-Host "Tell me a file path"
    $filePath
}

Describe "Test-Foo" {
  Context "When something" {
        Mock Read-Host {return "c:\example"}

        $result = Test-Foo

        It "Returns correct result" { # should work
            $result | Should Be "c:\example"
        }
         It "Returns correct result" { # should not work
            $result | Should Be "SomeThingWrong"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When i run it it still hangs on the Read-Host line though?

`PS D:\Temp\Scrap> invoke-pester





Describing Test-Foo
   Context When something
Tell me a file path:`

Comment: I have changed the example, Can you please try to coppy this to a new ps1 and test if you have the desired result?

Comment: That does work! 
In my test I have the function I want to test in a separate psm1 file. I must be importing it wrong.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This example does not currently work for me in Pester v5

Comment: The `Mock` statement is contextual on Pester v5. You can move the `Mock` statement into `BeforeAll {}` section within the `Describe {}` section, or into the same `It {}` section where you use `Read-Host`.

Answer (score 0):

An extension to [Bert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41285492/795137), this is the updated code sample for Pester v5.

The difference from Pester v4 is that [Mocks are scoped based on their placement](https://pester.dev/docs/usage/mocking#mocks-are-scoped-based-on-their-placement).

```
Function Test-Foo {
    $filePath = Read-Host "Tell me a file path"
    $filePath
}

Describe "Test-Foo" {

    BeforeAll {
        # Variables placed here is accessible by all Context sections.
        $returnText = "c:\example"
    }

    Context "When something" {

        BeforeAll {
            # You can mock here so every It gets to use this mock
            Mock Read-Host {return $returnText}
        }

        It "Returns correct result" {
            # Place mock codes here for the current It context
            # Mock Read-Host {return $returnText}

            $result = Test-Foo
            $result | Should Be $returnText
        }
    }
}
```